# Which google service for dockerized app not requiring http request?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a dockerized app that i currently run by calling its name in a terminal. (Local)

This app is retrieving data from websockets and recording it in files and finally forwarding them to Google Cloud Storage.
When run in a container, its start is trigerred in the Dockerfile by use of 'ENTRYPOINT'.

I thought i could use Google Cloud Run to run this dockerized app, but i could read in the documentation

"The service has to listen to HTTP requests"

"If there is no request, vCPU is scaled down to 0"
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/developing

This app is not a website that listens to http request.
I understand that Google Cloud Run is not suited to run this kind of app in the cloud.

Please which Google Cloud product is best suited for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have access to websockets GCP has two contenerized alternatives.

The first one is using a serverless alternative which is [App Engine Flex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-websockets-and-session-affinity) That when deploying a custom runtime the deployment is actually done with a container image.
This alternative allows you to have the App engine Auto Scaling with at least 1 instance running.

The Second Alternative is to use a GKE cluster where you can deploy containers, this one has more control on your side which will allow you to perform more variaty of tasks, however being less managed will algo imply more managemet task for you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for trying to help. Websocket is not the topic, sorry. The question is: which Google product allows running easily a containerized application (doker) that is running 24/7? (Google Cloud Run appears to expect containerized application listening to a port for HTTP requests to be executed)

Comment: to run dockerized apps the options are in serverless App Engine, and CloudRun, or on managed infrastructure GKE, as you mentiones that need to access websockets app engine standard and cloudrun wont apply as they are blocked to access Websockets. 
to be running 24/7 App engine Flex and GKE apply, just take in consideration that in app engine flex the instance will be restarted once a week, and in GKE the pods are considered premptible which means by they can get restarted as well.

Comment: this two alternatives you can easily configure them to write to Cloud Storage using the CLIs

Comment: ok, thanks I will have a look to check if App Engine Flex can allow me to run 24/7 a python program that is dockerized. Thanks

Comment: To run the dockerized application you would need to use a custom runtime [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml) is how to do the app configuration.  and [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-instances-are-managed) is the explanation on how the instances are managed and that they will be running continously.